# Multiple Checkbox save Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, checkbox

I managed yet to save my text value and checkbox value trough a save button.  Now i want to create 2 (or more) checkboxes, but with current code, it just saves one, not the rest...  It must be a small change i have to make, but i can't seem to find it...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainCamperTime extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

CheckBox checkBox;
EditText editText;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_camper_time);

    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    loadSavedPreferences();
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CheckBox_Value", false);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "Wanneer vertrekken?");
    if (checkBoxValue) {
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }

    editText.setText(name);
}

private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", checkBox.isChecked());
    if (checkBox.isChecked())
        savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using same key for different checkbox.

Replace below onClick() method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    savePreferences(((CheckBox)findViewById(v.getId())).getText(), checkBox.isChecked());
    if (checkBox.isChecked())
        savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());

    finish();
}
```

When you retrieve checkbox value from sharePreference then you need to pass checkbox's text as a key in sharePreference like below:

```
boolean checkBoxValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(checkBox.getText(), false);
```

Comment: tnx for the quick reply. If i make those changes, the (((CheckBox)v.getId()) gets underlined, and the error message tells me: cannot cast int to checkbox ?

Comment: ok, added, gives me no more errors... but program stops on testing.  I guess i should change something in this string to:   checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); ?
Also, safepreferences in your solution gave me error, but i solved in the way that i added this:  private void savePreferences(CharSequence text, boolean checked) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }. Perhaps something's not right the way i do...

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the checkbox CheckChangedListner as below:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
            savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", true);
                          savePreferences("storedName", editText.getText().toString());
            } else {
            savePreferences("CheckBox_Value", true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Same for the second checkbox.